# Basic "mate in one move" puzzle - what am I missing?

Tags: learning, problems, beginner

I am extremely new to chess and have been working through some "mate in one" problems on chesspuzzles.com for practice. This one has me very confused though:

[image: A mate in on chess problem]

The stated answer is:

> Bg6#

But why? Can't black's king move to d8 or e7 after that? I feel like I must be missing something very obvious, but can't for the life of me see what it is...

Comment: You are missing a piece. 

Answer (score 26):

You are absolutely right! The black king can move to d8 and e7 and then there's no follow up mate. Most probably there's a white queen/bishop on h4 to prevent the black king from escaping (which is not shown in the figure). In that case, Bg6# is a checkmate.

```
[Title "Mate in One"]
[FEN "r1b1kb1r/pp1n2p1/1qp1p2p/8/2PP3Q/3B1N2/P4PPP/R4RK1 w Qkq - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Given the difference in material, most likely a queen.

Comment: I'd guess a bishop that chased away the black queen from her starting square. I wonder if this is some known opening trap.

Comment: I suspect a sacrifice on e6 with queen and black bishop on h4 or g5 most probably g5?. Bg5 h6.qxe6 fxe6 bg6

Comment: Could also be a white knight on c6 instead of the black pawn.

Comment: @cmgchess: +1, my first idea too.

Comment: @cmgchess White bishop I presume, not black bishop, but yes, that looks plausible as a way White could lose the queen, and it explains bPh6.

Comment: So the answer is really "the puzzle is wrong"?